# Is it possible to vertically arrange two gauge charts inside one box?

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny

I'd like to position two gauge charts (flexdashboard) in vertical order in the same box, but I can't think of a way how.
Is this even possible? If so, I'd appreciate a lot if someone could help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nckh, can you include a small reprex for this?

Comment: issue has been solved. I just used br() inside the box.